# Phonegap Cordova - Trying to connect to public IP server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, server

I'm trying to log into my node.js server via app on my android phone. This program works fine pretty much everywhere I run, until I compile it with phonegap and intall on my android phone for testing. It shows "Connecting to Server...", and that's it. Although, when I write the IP address into my android phone's browser, it connects fine. Is there something I need to do for this being available? If not, how do I do this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
    window.location.href = "http://192.168.1.11:8080";

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<h1>Connecting to Server...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correct CSP and possibly an access-origin entry in your config.xml (depending on cordova version, doesn't hurt to have both).

However what you are trying to do will not work in the Cordova environment as is. The short answer is a Cordova app is a self contained web app and trying to redirect / change the body via window.location.href would take you out of the app which is not allowed. (That is not 100% exactly what is going on, but that is a much longer answer).

To fire up external web content you would need to add the in-app browser plugin and open your url in that:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled permissions for it to access a remote server?  If not then the local browser security policy is likely blocking it.

Check you have the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your HTML and your remote domain added to it.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://192.168.1.11:8080 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to cordova, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: Possible meta suggestion added - this worked for me (obviously I used a different URL :) )

Comment: I put the tag in the html head and re-compiled. No difference :(

Comment: Out of interest, what are you trying to achieve?  Perhaps there is another way of doing it.  Normally an app is responsible for display the data rather than displaying a remote page, which effectively means you're leaving the app.

Comment: The tag actually made it stop working and stay still on "connecting to server..." everywhere o_O

Comment: I'm hosting a node.js server on my computer and am trying to make a multiplayer game. This is all learning though.

Comment: But you're simply loading / redirecting to a remote page. The app should be retrieving data from the server and be displaying it within the app, not leaving the app.  Or am I reading things incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know if it leaves the app or not.. but yes it's supposed to retrieve data from the server.
When I execute the html on laptop independently, it briefly says Connecting to server... then brings up the game I have going on my node server.
Basically all I do is put the IP address into the bar and it works, now I'm trying to write an app that when you open it pretty much does that automatically.

Comment: So your app is merely a way of launching a web based game on a remote server, nothing more nothing less ?

Comment: The game is in the app already, but I want there to be a "multiplayer mode", when you click "Multiplayer", it connects people. That's it.

Comment: I'm trying lots of thing's, nothing helps :/